# How can I display user's total Friend invites without looping through each one?

Tags: solspace, solspace-friends

I'm using the Solspace Friends module, and I'm trying to figure out an easy way to set a badge displaying the users' total friend invites.

The documentation lists a tag: `{friends_total_results}`, but this tag only works inside the `{exp:friends:invites}` loop, which means it gets repeated for every instance of an invite that the loop returns.

Am I missing something here, or is this just simply not possible in this current veriosn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the tag you can place a conditional.
{if count == "1"}{friends_total_results}{/if}

so the total only displays once.

Or you could use the query module and run a query against the exp_friends table and display a single number.